# An adjective for an evaluation/criticism that is indifferent/careless about upsetting people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**Explanation**:

I should criticize/evaluate my colleague’s view **comfortably and without feeling it to be awkward.**

I should criticize/evaluate his view **without being careful that I don’t make him angry/upset/… .**

I **should not be shy** in criticizing/evaluating my fellow.

That is, in doing so I **should be indifferent or careless as to whether my evaluation/criticism upset people or not.**

**Examples**:

- Such evaluation/criticism is ______ .
- An academic shouldn’t be shy in criticizing her fellows’ views; she should not care that their fellows might become upset of her criticism. Academic work is supposedly based on ______ criticism/evaluation.

I want an adjective for the above blanks.

*Reckless*, *careless*, and *impersonal* come to mind, but each might have other connotations. I want to see if there is any common/idiomatic word/phrase for such contexts.

Comment: regardless of who holds the view.

Comment: You seem to be using “careless” incorrectly. This suggests to me that  you should try English Language Learners, even though I have provided an answer.

Comment: Your use of the term "ruthless" in your edits makes confusing finding this  term in answers that actually proposed it before  your correction. A note in your text making that clear wouldn't be superfluous.

Comment: @LPH Sorry for any ambiguity. What I tried to say is that I want an adjective for an attitude in criticism where one doesn’t take personal things into considerations. That can be said by words such as objective/impartial/scientific. But I wanted to emphasize that the critique is not shy considering personal things.

Comment: @Sasan That is not what I am talking  about. The word "ruthless" didn't appear in your post at first (only "reckless" was in before you made  a  change) and that is why I could propose it in my answer; now it looks as if I didn't read your post or pretended not to see the word "ruthless" in it.

Comment: @LPH Got it. Omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this new version of the question there seems to exist in my idiolect a term that answers to the stated credo. I am thinking of the adjective "*uninhibited*".

- Such evaluation/criticism is *uninhibited*.
- An academic shouldn’t be shy in criticizing her fellows’ views; she should not care that their fellows might become upset of her criticism. Academic work is supposedly based on *uninhibited* criticism/evaluation.

Comment: I think this is as near as one is likely to come to satisfying both examples. I had considered “uncompromising” which is similar but I think more negative. I have deleted my original suggestion “insensitive” which I think worked with the original, but not with the current version.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the exact context, it's hard to provide an ideal word, but several are possible, including blunt, honest, candid, unflinching, unsparing, plainspoken, and forthright. A thesaurus will provide even more options.

Comment: It is hard to see why these suggestions were downvoted. All are valid and all give the PO relevant lead-ins to explore in reference sources. I appreciate that we are encouraged to give sources for our answers but always to insist on that is to be over-punctilious. I have compensated.

Comment: Thank you, @Anton. I did consider including definitions with links, but that seemed excessive, especially since there is no real indication that the author might not know the meanings of any of the words. If anyone objects, please let me know and I'd be happy to include definitions of all of the terms.

Comment: I think "blunt criticism" fits the criteria perfectly. +1

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [**disinterested**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disinterested) conveys what you're trying to get across:

> having no personal involvement or receiving no personal advantage, and therefore free to act fairly:
>
> - a disinterested observer/judgment
> - a piece of disinterested advice

It does have an unfortunate feature of commonly being used "incorrectly" these days.

> Note: Disinterested is sometimes used to mean not interested, but many people consider this use to be incorrect. Compare uninterested.

Similar words whose meanings aren't as easily confused could also fit;  many have already been suggested (e.g. impartial, unbiased, objective), but there's also [**dispassionate**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dispassionate):

> able to think clearly or make good decisions because of not being influenced by emotions

You seem to be looking for words that have to do with how you or your colleague (potentially) feel about your criticism; in some sense, however, that's a different matter than whether your feelings *affect* your criticism. (For example you can make valid, objective, impartial criticism that's completely about the work being critiqued and not influenced by your like/dislike of your colleague and still be worried it might be taken the wrong way or hurt your colleague's feelings—and if it does so that still doesn't affect the impartiality of the critique.) In any case, **disinterested** and **dispassionate** fit your example sentences and have the advantage of suggesting that your own feelings weren't a consideration in your criticism and, by implication, your colleague's weren't (for you) and shouldn't be (for them) either.

Answer (score 0):

Your title and your text suggest that you are willing to offend if necessary, or are indifferent to the giving of offence.

Please note that I do not write *willing* in the sense of wanting or wishing to, merely of doing something if necessary:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/willing)
> *willing*:
> to be happy to do something if it is needed
> *willingness*:
> the quality of being happy to do something if it is needed

Relevant words in these circumstances are *frank*, *outspoken* and *forthright*. I slightly prefer the last but the others are useful, depending on the balance you want to strike between honesty and rudeness:

Your criticism is **forthright**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forthright)
> *forthright*:
> free from ambiguity or evasiveness : going straight to the point

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forthright)
> *forthright*:
> (too) honest or direct in behaviour:
> *His forthright manner can be mistaken for rudeness.*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frank)
> *frank*
> honest, sincere, and telling the truth, even when this might be awkward or make other people uncomfortable

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outspoken)
> *outspoken*
> expressing strong opinions very directly without worrying if other people are offended

Comment: I think that you misread the title; it contains two instances of "not".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I considered that but on rereading I now agree with you. The title implies a willingness  to upset, as does the text. I have edited but the core of my answer still stands. Thanks.

Comment: @Anton Neither the title nor the text imply a willingness to upset. They imply carelessness or indifference as to upsetting or not upsetting those who are criticized.

Comment: @sasan Fair comment. I use *willing* in the sense of tolerating or of being indifferent. I do not use it in the sense of wishing or wanting to. I have edited with an added definition of willing and willingness purely to clarify this. I am of course willing to be criticized on this point, as on so many others.

Answer (score 0):

A single adjective will never capture these two ideas to any appreciable degree of exactess; it is better to rely on two adjectives.

I believe the adjective "*impartial*" is exactly what is needed for the first part.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/impartial?q=impartial))
> **impartial** adjective
> not supporting one person or group more than another
> synonyms: neutral, unbiased
>
> •  an impartial inquiry/observer
> •  to give impartial advice
> •  As chairman, I must remain impartial.

For the secod, "*ruthless*" is pretty much what the OP's definition  corresponds to.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ruthless?q=ruthless)) **ruthless** adjective (often disapproving)
>
> •    a ruthless dictator
> •    The way she behaved towards him was utterly ruthless.
> •   He has a ruthless determination to succeed.
> •   We’ll have to be ruthless if we want to make this company more efficient.

In my opinion "reckless" is not at all the proper term for this second part.

- Such evaluation/criticism is impartial and ruthless.

As options connoting a lesser degree of disregard for people's feelings there are two other terms: *unrelenting* and *relentless*. ((SOED *unrelenting*: Not softening or yielding; *esp* not giving way to kindess or compassion),((SOED) *relentless*: Incapable of relenting; pitiless, insistent and uncompromising. Also […] oppressively constant))

- Such evaluation/criticism is impartial and unrelenting.
- Such evaluation/criticism is impartial and relentless.

Answer (score -1):

***Objective*** evaluation:

> not influenced by personal feelings or opinions in considering and representing facts. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=objective%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&biw=1536&bih=664&sxsrf=ALiCzsZDQq63I__G0GGqo_GziWBb9Fa5ZQ%3A1661019782827&ei=hiYBY-iJMtS_gQay6IPoAw&oq=objective%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADINCAAQgAQQsQMQRhD5ATIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoHCAAQgAQQCjoECAAQDUoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDNBliTJGCwLmgCcAF4AIABgwGIAZ4HkgEDOC4ymAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps "Indiscriminate Criticism", "Apathetic Criticism" or "Indifferent criticism"?

Comment: You should add some explanation of why you think this is a good term in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).